# How can I find the SQL Server logins that have no server privs and have no database access?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to create a script that will go through and list the logins that have no server-wide privs AND have no access to databases.

I have a lot of logins that were generated on my SQL Server 2005 instance and are no longer used. I want to quickly find and delete these logins.

Thanks,

Niko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-phrased my question and got a response:

[Is there a SQL Server Utility that generates a big list of all Server Logins and an overview of their access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523114/is-there-a-sql-server-utility-that-generates-a-big-list-of-all-server-logins-and)

The script provided can be used to compare to the list of Server Logins and then if a Login does not appear in the results then it should be investigated for deletion

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion, this is not something that should be done quickly. It is also nothing that I would trust a script to do. I would analyze each account, and I would make sure myself that the account does not have any permissions. I'd manually delete them and **document** the accounts that were removed.

Comment: well even if I could list them it would be great. I believe there are a hundred or so accounts I am looking for.