# Is there a SQL Server Utility that generates a big list of all Server Logins and an overview of their access?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to know if there is a utility out there that can list the Server Logins on a particular server and their access.

This would be the information I get from right clicking each user -> Properties -> User Mapping
but instead of manually going through that process for each user, it just lists the information.

For example:

```
MyDomain\John
 - Server Roles
   - sysadmin
 - MyDatabase1
   - Roles
     db_reader
     public
 - MyDatabase2
   - Roles
     db_reader
     public
MyDomain\Steve
 - MyDatabase1
   - Roles
     db_reader
     public
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hacked up the sp_helplogins system stored procedure to return close to what you're looking for.

I can't get the script to paste correctly so here is a [link](http://cid-c58c2473d934ad72.office.live.com/self.aspx/Clipboard/StackOverflow5523114.sql) to the script.

```
DECLARE    @LoginNamePattern     sysname    = NULL

set nocount on

declare
        @exec_stmt nvarchar(3550)

declare
       @CountSkipPossUsers             int
      ,@Int1                           int

declare
       @c10DBName                      sysname
      ,@c10DBStatus                    int
      ,@c10DBSID                       varbinary(85)

declare
       @charMaxLenLoginName            varchar(11)
      ,@charMaxLenDBName               varchar(11)
      ,@charMaxLenUserName             varchar(11)

declare
       @DBOptLoading                   int   --0x0020      32  "DoNotRecover"
      ,@DBOptPreRecovery               int   --0x0040      64
      ,@DBOptRecovering                int   --0x0080     128

      ,@DBOptSuspect                   int   --0x0100     256  ("not recovered")
      ,@DBOptOffline                   int   --0x0200     512
      ,@DBOptDBOUseOnly                int   --0x0800    2048

      ,@DBOptSingleUser                int   --0x1000    4096


-------------  create work holding tables  ----------------
-- Create temp tables before any DML to ensure dynamic


CREATE TABLE #tb1_UA
   (
    LoginName                       sysname     collate database_default NOT Null
   ,DBName                          sysname     collate database_default NOT Null
   ,UserName                        sysname     collate database_default NOT Null
   )




---------------  Cursor, for DBNames  -------------------


declare ms_crs_10_DB
   Cursor local static For
select
             name ,status ,sid
      from
             master.dbo.sysdatabases



OPEN ms_crs_10_DB


-----------------  LOOP 10:  thru Databases  ------------------


WHILE (10 = 10)
   begin    --LOOP 10: thru Databases


   FETCH
             next
      from
             ms_crs_10_DB
      into
             @c10DBName
            ,@c10DBStatus
            ,@c10DBSID


   IF (@@fetch_status <> 0)
      begin
      deallocate ms_crs_10_DB
      BREAK
      end


--------------------  Okay if we peek inside this DB now?


   IF (     @c10DBStatus & @DBOptDBOUseOnly  > 0
       AND  @c10DBSID                       <> suser_sid()
      )
      begin
      select @CountSkipPossUsers = @CountSkipPossUsers + 1
      CONTINUE
      end


   IF (@c10DBStatus & @DBOptSingleUser  > 0)
      begin

      select    @Int1 = count(*)
         from   sys.dm_exec_requests
         where  session_id <> @@spid
         and    database_id = db_id(@c10DBName)

      IF (@Int1 > 0)
         begin
         select @CountSkipPossUsers = @CountSkipPossUsers + 1
         CONTINUE
         end
      end


   IF (@c10DBStatus &
         (
           @DBOptLoading
         | @DBOptRecovering
         | @DBOptSuspect
         | @DBOptPreRecovery
         )
               > 0
      )
      begin
      select @CountSkipPossUsers = @CountSkipPossUsers + 1
      CONTINUE
      end


   IF (@c10DBStatus &
         (
           @DBOptOffline
         )
               > 0
      )
      begin
      --select @CountSkipPossUsers = @CountSkipPossUsers + 1
      CONTINUE
      end

    IF (has_dbaccess(@c10DBName) <> 1)
      begin
      raiserror(15622,-1,-1, @c10DBName)
      CONTINUE
      end



---------------------  Add the User info to holding table.
    select @exec_stmt = '
   INSERT    #tb1_UA
            (
             DBName
            ,LoginName
            ,UserName
            )
      select

             N' + quotename(@c10DBName, '''') + '
            ,l.name
            ,u2.name
         from
             ' + quotename(@c10DBName, '[')+ '.sys.database_role_members m
            ,' + quotename(@c10DBName, '[')+ '.sys.database_principals u1
            ,' + quotename(@c10DBName, '[')+ '.sys.database_principals u2
            ,sys.server_principals l
         where
             u1.sid = l.sid
         and m.member_principal_id = u1.principal_id
         and m.role_principal_id = u2.principal_id' +
            case 
            when @LoginNamePattern is null
            then ''
            else ' and ( l.name = N' + quotename(@LoginNamePattern , '''') + '
                or l.name = N' + quotename(@LoginNamePattern , '''') + ')'
            end

   EXECUTE(@exec_stmt)

   end --loop 10


------------  Optimize UA report column display widths  -----------


select
             @charMaxLenLoginName   =
                  convert ( varchar
                           ,isnull ( max(datalength(LoginName)) ,9)
                          )
            ,@charMaxLenDBName      =
                  convert ( varchar
                           ,isnull ( max(datalength(DBName)) ,6)
                          )
            ,@charMaxLenUserName    =
                  convert ( varchar
                           ,isnull ( max(datalength(UserName)) ,8)
                          )
      from
             #tb1_UA



------------  Print out the UserOrAlias report  ------------

EXEC(
'
set nocount off


select
          ''LoginName''    = substring (LoginName  ,1 ,'
                                       + @charMaxLenLoginName  + ')

         ,''DBName''       = substring (DBName     ,1 ,'
                                       + @charMaxLenDBName     + ')

         ,''MemberOf''     = substring (UserName   ,1 ,'
                                       + @charMaxLenUserName   + ')

   from
          #tb1_UA
   order by
          1 ,2 ,3


Set nocount on
'
)

DROP Table #tb1_UA
```

Comment: Pastes all right for me? If you are using IE there seems to be a problem with the markdown at the moment where copying code from a post and pasting elsewhere removes all line breaks is that the issue you were having?

Comment: I am using Chrome and it was dropping LF/CR whenever there was a commented line of code thus munging the code. Thanks for pasting it in.